# Why is it not adding to my database?

Tags: php, mysql

Why is SESSION variable not adding to database?
I only receive my score value, but not username.
Note:
Session variable is defined as below:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST[username];
```

This is the part I am having trouble with:

```
session_start(); 
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$con = mysql_connect("something.hosting.com","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("quiz", $con);

$sql="
INSERT INTO members (
    Name, Score
) VALUES (
    '$user', '$max_value'
)
";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
```

1. Yes, I did start session.
2. When I try to echo the variable on the second page, It does output correctly.
3. Did try mysql escape

Comment: Have you started the session with ``session_start()`` before you assign the ``$_SESSION`` variable?

Comment: If you echo out the SQL and then try to execute it by hand, do you get any errors?

Comment: Remember to escape your input variables to prevent SQL injections. ``$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);``

Comment: It depends what's the output of `$_SESSION['username']`. Whilst the comment of @CheeseSucker is indeed very valid, the OP suggests that one value is inserted suggesting the query doesn't fail. OP, what's the data type of the column `Name`? I suspect it's something incompatible with the contents of `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: 1)Yes, I did start session. 2)When I try to echo the variable on the second page, It does output correctly. 3)Did try mysql escape

Comment: @Ben data type is varchar(255) while username is just input type="text"

Comment: Where does `$max_value` come from? The session too or somewhere else?

Comment: here is the website http://celljawns.com/quiz/   if that helps. Note, I echoed the username on top of the second page

Comment: @Ben $max_value is the number of correct answers that user got on the quiz. It's on the same page as mySQL connection.

Comment: Did you enable error reporting? Try putting `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors','On');` at the top of your script.

Comment: @Mike I just put it. You can check it yourself: celljawns.com/quiz

Comment: Also, instead of echoing the varible, echo `$sql`. That should give you an idea of what's being put into the database.

Comment: I've just run a test of this and can't replicate it. The code you've given above works fine on my machine. At what point do you do `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST[username];`. Is it before or after both `session_start()` and `$user = $_SESSION['username']; `

Comment: @JayBerd, Try getting those errors fixed. I'm not sure if it's because I am not logged in, but I'm getting a LOT of session related errors on the second page. They may be unrelated, but who knows?

Comment: `$user = $_SESSION['username'];` and `session_start()` are on different page while `$user = $_SESSION['username'];` is on results page.

Comment: You need to properly configure the session.save_path in your `php.ini` or `.htaccess` file by the looks of it. Try `session.save_path='/tmp';`. Also look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php

Comment: @Mike I am not familiar with that

Comment: What is the contents of `$sql`?

Comment: @Mike INSERT INTO members (Name, Score) VALUES ('', '7')

Comment: So your problem is the `$user` variable. It has nothing to do with MySQL. Work backwards and try echoing that variable at every step of the way all the way back to `$_POST['username'];` (you should be using quotes there, as mentioned earlier) and find out where it is failing. I still think it's likely your `session.save_path` being messed up.

Comment: Ok thanks for much information! I will work on it now

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are setting  $_SESSION['username'] incorrectly.  You have left out the quotes when getting the $_POST value.

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST[username];
```

should be

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Comment: Won't PHP interpret that `username` as a string literal in that context? http://codepad.org/DZvjCUtX (Not saying it's a good idea, but should work... right?)

Comment: When I changed it, it gave me this error:
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
The script had an error or it did not produce any output. If there was an error, you should be able to see it in the error log.

Comment: I've never seen that done before.   I'm not aware of any feature where it would interpret username as string.  Thanks for the link though.  I guess that works, Although it's probably something I wouldn't recommend using.

Comment: @Kibbee An undefined constant is interpreted as a string. Weird, but true. [CodePad](http://codepad.org/aM2eqibB).